# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SingleBlockManager'

Tags: python

How can I solve the error? Here is my code:

```
df['Intensity'] = norm((df['Mean'] - y_value)/df['Std'])
```

I want to plot a barplot with an interactive color band. When I run this line of code (which is part of my full code) I get the error message:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SingleBlockManager'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The `SingleBlockManager` is a Pandas internal data structure. Meaning the function `norm` you're calling probably doesn't take a Pandas dataframe, but rather an array.

You can make an array by calling `values` from the dataframe.

```
df['Intensity'] = norm(((df['Mean'] - y_value)/df['Std']).values)
```

Or easier to read:

```
norm_df = (df['Mean'] - y_value) / df['Std']
df['Intensity'] = norm(norm_df.values)
```